# Titan - How to Use 'Lucene' Search Backend

Tags: titan

I am attempting to use the `lucene` search backend with Titan.  I am setting the `index.search.backend` property to `lucene` as so.

```
TitanFactory.Builder config = TitanFactory.build();
config.set("storage.backend", "hbase");
config.set("storage.hostname", "node1");
config.set("storage.hbase.table", "titan");
config.set("index.search.backend", "lucene");
config.set("index.search.directory", "/tmp/foo");

TitanGraph graph = config.open();
GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(graph);
graph.getVertices().forEach(v -> System.out.println(v.toString()));
```

Of course, this does not work because this setting is of the `GLOBAL_OFFLINE` variety.  The logs make me aware of this.  Titan ignores my 'lucene' setting and then attempts to use Elasticsearch as the search backend.

```
WARN com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration  
- Local setting index.search.backend=lucene (Type: GLOBAL_OFFLINE) 
is overridden by globally managed value (elasticsearch).  Use 
the ManagementSystem interface instead of the local configuration to control 
this setting.
```

After some reading, I understand that I need to use the Management System to set the `index.search.backend`.  I need some code that looks something like the following.

```
graph.getManagementSystem().set("index.search.backend", "lucene");
graph.getManagementSystem().set("index.search.directory", "/tmp/foo");
graph.getManagementSystem().commit();
```

I am confused on how to integrate this in my original example code above. Since this is a `GLOBAL_OFFLINE` setting, I cannot set this on an open graph.  At the same time, I do not know how to get a graph unless I open one first.  How do I set the search backend correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `inmemory` search backend. The [supported search backends](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/index-backends.html) are Lucene, Solr, and Elasticsearch.

[Lucene](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/lucene.html) is a good option for a small scale, single machine search backend. You need to set 2 properties to do this, `index.search.backend` and `index.search.directory`:

```
index.search.backend=lucene
index.search.directory=/path/to/titansearchindexdir
```

As you've noted, the search backend is a `GLOBAL_OFFLINE`, so you should configure this before initially creating your graph. Since you've already created a `titan` table in your HBase, either disable and drop the `titan` table, or set your graph configuration to point at a new `storage.hbase.table`.

Comment: I opened an issue related to this https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/1332

Comment: You are correct, but I misspoke.  The same thing occurs if I attempt to use Lucene.  Thanks for catching this.  I will update the question.

Comment: Did you drop the HBase table?